# notepad++ regex replace word in first line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Im trying to use the following regex to search and replace in multiple files in notepad++

```
([^\n]*)(state="1")([^\n]*)*.
```

This searches and finds state="1" in the first line of each file and works fine.

However, when I try to replace state="1" using:

```
Replace with: $1 state="5"
```

it cuts off the rest of the line.

I thought that it might be possible to get the rest of the line using:

```
Replace with: $1 state="5" $2
```

However, $2 doesnt seem to exist as a variable.

Is there some way to attach the rest of the line into variable $2?

Cheers

Heres an image to show how 
    (?=\A[^\n]*)state="1"
is not working

Ive updated my version of notepad++ and everything
[image: notworking]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each capture group, `(…)`, is assigned a number, so `$2` represents the second capture group, `(state="1")`. The remainder of the line is captured in `$3`.

Either remove the capture group around `state="1"`:

```
([^\n]*)state="1"([^\n]*)*.
```

Or use `$3`:

```
Replace with: $1 state="5" $3
```

Also, given the simplicity of the task, I don't see why you couldn't just search for `state="1"` and replace with `state="5"`. There doesn't seem to be any need for regular expressions here.

---

**Update** There's nothing in the pattern listed so far which limits the result to *only* matching strings on the first line. If you need that I'd recommend using a pattern like this:

```
(?=\A[^\n]*)state="1"
```

With these settings:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Update** There seems to be some strange behavior with the `\A` (beginning of text) anchor inside the lookbehind. Removing from the lookbehind seems to work. Try this pattern:

```
\A([^\n]*)state="1"
```

And replace with:

```
$1state="5"
```

All the other settings should be fine.

Comment: Its really strange, when I try to replace with $3 in a file that is opened in notepad++ it replaces the first line correctly, but when I try to do it in multiple files, it replaces every occurance (not just those on the first line)

Comment: hmmn strange,     (?=\A[^\n]*)state="1"    this regex doesnt seem to find any of the occurrances of state="1"

Comment: @Ke. I tested it out and it seems to work. You might want to try enabling 'Wrap around' if you're testing it within a single file.

Comment: Its weird it just says "cant find the text (?=\A[^\n]*)state="1"" :/ all my settings are exactly the same as yours, and tried word wrap too

Comment: @Ke. Can you show a short sample of the kind of file you're working with? I tested using a file which simply had `state="1"` repeated on 3 separate lines.

Comment: Have uploaded an image but essentially I have - <WINDOW class="Container" text="Find" x="0" y="0" width="1008" height="708" id="132" state="1" group="0">

Comment: @Ke. Okay it seems to be the some strange behavior of the lookbehind.  See my updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: You're and absolute gem. Works great. Thanks for working so relentlessly to solve this :) I had to use $1 state=5 in the replace field, but worked perfecly. Thanks so much :) Lookbehind seems really cool, must look more into this